# How to merge date and time into 1 object

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate

My data is this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1509408000, 1509408000, 1509408000, 
1509408000, 1509408000, 1509408000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(-2208988860, -2208988920, 
-2208988980, -2208989040, -2208989100, -2208989160), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), O = c(54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 
54.63, 54.63), H = c(54.63, 54.63, 54.62, 54.62, 54.63, 54.63
), L = c(54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62), C = c(54.62, 
54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62, 54.62), date.time = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want the time to either have the same date as in the Date column or have no date at all. 
For the first solution, I have tried to take the date from Date column and the time from the Time column to create a datetime column.

I have tried the following code:

```
data_frame2$date.time <- as.POSIXct(paste0(data_frame2$Date,  data_frame2$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

but I get NA in the date.time column created.

I have also tried getting rid of the date with:

```
data_frame2_date_filter$Time <- format(ymd_hms(data_frame2_date_filter$Time), "%H:%M:%S")

atr_results$Time <- parse_date_time(atr_results$Time, "HMS")
atr_results$Time <- times(strftime(atr_results$Time, format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

but these don't work either.

Comment: You can just extract  the time. `format(df$Time, "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: 1. Extract hour information from the `Time` column; 2. Paste using `paste`, not `paste0`. `as.POSIXct((paste(df$Date, strftime(df$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))))`. There might be a duplicate for this.

Comment: Just about to post what @PoGibas posted. You can also just use `%T` instead of `%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: when I tried data_frame2$date.time <- as.POSIXct((paste(data_frame2$Date, strftime(data_frame2$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))))  the times in new column were changed: first row time was 
 23:59:00  now 01:23:00 second row time was 23:58:00 now now 01:22:00

Comment: You have to specify time zone in `as.POSIXct`, try `tz = "UTC"`

Comment: Yes adding tz = "UTC" created the correct times